# If $S\subset T \subset V$ and $T$ is a subspace of $V$ then prove that $L(S)\subset T$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $S\subset T \subset V$. Then $S\subset T$, $L(S) \subset L(T)$ and $T\subset L(T)$.

Why is $L(S)\subset T$?

Comment: Very confusing. $L$ is linear? In any case, false. Take $\{0\}\subset{\Bbb R}\subset{\Bbb C}$, $L =$ rotation ($\ne$ identity).

Comment: What is $L(-)$?

Comment: The question is "If $T\subset L(T)$ then $L(S)\subset T$?"?